# Event on change month

Tags: primefaces, schedule

my question is about schedule on primefaces.
is there a function that calls an event when i change month ?

I want to complete the month when it is changed.

Comment: you want to say if the user start insert a month you will give him a prpoposition about the month like in [Autocomplete example](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/autoComplete.xhtml) see the multiple example

Comment: there is AJAX Event when i click on button to change month?

Comment: when month is changed i want insert some events in some dates. but only if month is changed

Comment: SOLUTION: 

loadEvents on init method